# Issue with CKEditor 5 Easy Upload image in React filerepository-no-upload-adapter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor

I have a react application and I am trying to implement CKEditor image upload in it. However, even after following the documentation I still get the following error in the console whenever I try to upload an image `filerepository-no-upload-adapter`

I created a brand new app to test it out, but the results are the same.

The form is working great, but the upload options isn't. Here is the code:

```
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

 
function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CKEditor editor={ClassicEditor} data={text} onChange={(evt, editor) => {
        const data = editor.getData();
        setText(data);
      }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And I have added the following in @ckeditor/ckeditor5-cloud-services/src/cloudservices:

```
import EasyImage from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-easy-image/src/easyimage';
ClassicEditor
.create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {

   plugins: [ EasyImage ],
   toolbar: [ 'uploadImage' ],

    cloudServices: {
        tokenUrl: 'https://79538.cke-cs.com/token/dev/mytokenid',
        uploadUrl: 'https://79538.cke-cs.com/easyimage/upload/'
    }
} )
.then(  )
.catch(  );
```

I used the Easy Image upload URL and Development token URL provided in the CKEditor Ecosystem Dashboard for a quick setup, but it hasn't been working so far.

I read many articles and all of the related StackOverflow posts, besides the documentation but there isn't much on the problem that I could find.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Easy Image Plugin, because it's not free. I think your issue is that the code snippet you copied from their Doc is not for React.

You may try this in your react code

```
    <div className="App">
      <CKEditor 
        editor={ClassicEditor} 
        config={{
          extraPlugins: [EasyImage],
        }}
        //toolbar : [] // you may need to add 'uploadImage' toolbar
        data={text} onChange={(evt, editor) => {
        const data = editor.getData();
        setText(data);
      }} />
    </div>
```

BTW, I am the creator of https://www.npmjs.com/package/ckeditor5-build-classic-dna
It's created on the top of ckeditor5-build-classic with some features, like upload image from local (you need to set up an image server though), add Base64 image, insert an image by URL, or add an image from Unsplash, and other features.

Check my [demo page](https://deniapps.com/playground/ckeditor) for more settings to use CKEditor 5 with React (code snippets provided.)

Please let me know if you have any questions. I would be happy to help.